# Cache Function Import :: ADO.NET Entity Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching, ado.net

I have imported an SQL Stored Procedure using the built-in 'Function Import' of Visual Studio 2010.

I was wondering if there is a built-in, or custom, way to cache the results, just like you can cache a Control, or a Page, or even just a string; using the built-in Cache in .NET

If this needs more clarification, just let me know.

Thank you,
- Theo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity framework doesn't provide caching out of the box. There is [sample caching provider](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers) available but the description says that it works for Linq and ESQL queries. Stored procedures are not mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there isn't a built-in cache for function import result. But you can use the [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) class and wrap your function in a custom function that first check inside the cache.

Davide